# What is the Optimum center of mass location for an air-craft?

Tags: efficiency, cg

I was doing my mathematics exploration, and i would like to know what is the optimum center of mass location of a plane.

Specifically, what would happen if the point were to be too close or too far away from the point where the lift force was acting from. 
It would be helpful if you could cite a source for your information.

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on which aircraft, fuel amount and location, same for the payload. This can only be answered for a specific aircraft. By the way: CG is (for a B737) showed in percents in the FMC, not indicating a vertical location.

Comment: For limits and exceeding CG: [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11929/what-are-the-limits-to-lateral-centre-of-gravity-imbalances?rq=1)